# Consulting about the static google maps

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new in flash and I need your suggestions. I was making an application with the Google Maps API, using a key, for a long time but now when I launch the page, it is deprecated. I have seen other applications and it works with this API still. Do I have to change my application? I have looked at many ways to do with the static maps but I cannot find anything to help me.

Please I would appreciate any tip or suggestion. I am using Flash AS3 in CS5.

Comment: The Flash API for Google maps is [supposed to work until Sept 2, 2014](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/). I just checked several apps I wrote years ago and they are still working. I would guess yours should work too, but perhaps you're doing something a little more complicated than my simple apps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer,

sorry maybe I am going to ask something stupid, but because when I test the main swf and load others swfs files that load the map disappears all the content of the stage into the main swf?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Regards

Josy